# Id on Nfc tag not unique?

Tags: android, nfc

I am reading nfc tags on android phone, there is value which I written to the tag which I read like this:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Tag... params) {
    Tag tag = params[0];

    Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
    if (ndef == null) {
        // NDEF is not supported by this Tag.
        return null;
    }

    NdefMessage ndefMessage = ndef.getCachedNdefMessage();

    NdefRecord[] records = ndefMessage.getRecords();
    for (NdefRecord ndefRecord : records) {
        if (ndefRecord.getTnf() == NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN && Arrays.equals(ndefRecord.getType(), NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT)) {
            try {
                return readText(ndefRecord);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unsupported Encoding", e);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private String readText(NdefRecord record) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] payload = record.getPayload();
    String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16";                                               // Get the Text Encoding
    int languageCodeLength = payload[0] & 0063;                                                                         // Get the Language Code
    return new String(payload, languageCodeLength + 1, payload.length - languageCodeLength - 1, textEncoding);          // Get the Text
}
```

And there should be a unique Id of the NfcTag which is read only, I tried:

```
     Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
     mNfcId = tag.getId().toString();
```

But this is giving different results on next read !!!
How can I read the unique read only tag from nfc Tag ?

Answer (score 1):

There are tags that don't have a unique ID for privacy reasons. Most travel documents and credit cards that contain an NFC chip are among them.

Also: Don't count on the uniqueness of the IDs you can read. These can easily be faked. Also many manufacturers of NFC tags don't guarantee the worldwide uniqueness of the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what Nils already explained in his post, using `toString()` on a byte array won't give you useful information about the content of the byte array. Instead use a method like this, to convert the UID byte array into a string representation:

```
public static String convertByteArrayToHexString (byte[] b) {
    if (b != null) {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(2 * b.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; ++i) {
            final String t = Integer.toHexString(b[i]);
            final int l = t.length();
            if (l > 2) {
                s.append(t.substring(l - 2));
            } else {
                if (l == 1) {
                    s.append("0");
                }
                s.append(t);
            }
        }
        return s.toString();
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```